# Deserialize an RSS feed in C#.Net

Tags: xml, arrays, c#-4.0, deserialization

i'm very new to deserialization, but i've been given the task of deserializing several feeds and pulling out the data for manipulation.

i've got this RSS feed that's structured like this:

```
    <channel>
        <title></title>
        <link></link>
        <description></description>
        <ttl></ttl>
        <item>
            <title></title>
            <link></link>
            <description></description>
            <pubDate></pubDate>
            <guid></guid>
        </item>
        <item>
```

in my program i have the following class structure

```
[XmlRoot("channel")]
public class RahChannel
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public string link { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ttl")]
    public int ttl { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("item")]
    public ItemSet[] ItemArray { get; set; }
 }

[XmlArray]
class ItemSet
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string itemtitle { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public string itemLink { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string itemDescription { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("pubDate")]
    public string pubDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("guid")]
    public string guid { get; set; }
}
```

i'm using the system.xml.serialization class obviously.

My concern is that elements the array of Items won't get the values they should because they share names with elements outside the array, also have i created the array correctly?.

i've been using this structure to deserialize JSON feeds, and it worked there, but i'm not sure if i've translated it accross properly.

and what is the actual method for deserializing XML? i know what MSDN says i can do (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but i just want to confirm.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XSD to generate the class from your XML Schema

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: cheers, took some time to work out how the thing worked, but i think i've got it.  being able to see how the auto-generated class is structured makes it easier to see how i should do mine.

Answer (score 1):

Make the itemSet class public.
Also, have a look at this project: http://argotic.codeplex.com/ - maybe you don't need to implement the same functionality.

Comment: i missed setting the class to public, thanks.
i've been specifically told not to download any third party plugins or classes for this project, as the final version will end up on a cloud.  everything needs to be done with the tools available in Visual Studio 2010